# Finding the intersection of two three-dimensional functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have two large equations, both of the same form which I am trying to find the intersections of. The equations are:
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{\frac{x ^ 2}{r_1} + \frac{y ^ 2}{r_2}} {1 + \sqrt{1 - \frac{p_1 x ^ 2}{ r_1 ^ 2} - \frac{p_2 y ^ 2}{r_2 ^ 2}}} + b \\
g(x, y) = \frac{\frac{x ^ 2}{s_1} + \frac{y ^ 2}{s_2}} {1 + \sqrt{1 - \frac{q_1 x ^ 2}{ s_1 ^ 2} - \frac{q_2 y ^ 2}{s_2 ^ 2}}} + c
$$
What I seek is a two-dimensional equation $h(x)$ where for any value of $x$ the value of $y$ is provided. I have proceeded by attempting to solve
$$
f(x, y) - g(x, y) = 0
$$
for $y$. For example in a much easier case, if 
$$
f(x, y) = ax ^ 2 + by ^ 2 + c \\
g(x, y) = dx ^ 2 + ey^2 + f
$$
then
$$h(x) = \sqrt{\frac{f-c-x^2(a-d)}{b-e}}$$
I have tried to do this with pen and paper then with Wolfram Alpha then with SymPy but I can't get anything! Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't even know if it is possible or not so any advice or references would be warmly received.

Comment: You could look at the implicit function theorem.

Comment: As a matter of terminology, we don't say two functions *intersect*.  Their graphs or solution sets can intersect, or you can ask where the functions agree.